# Custom FireMonkey component does not get drawn

Tags: user-interface, paint, c++builder, firemonkey, c++builder-10.2-tokyo

Working in C++Builder 10.2 Tokyo, I am trying to add a custom component to a FireMonkey `TForm` programmatically at runtime.

The custom component is not installed as a package and registered in the IDE (as that ended up complicating the project too much), rather it is simply a subclass of `TPanel`.

However, The component, and its children, do not get drawn when I run the application. I have tested this on Windows and Android, and tried multiple modifications, like setting the Width and Height explicitly.

How can I fix this?

Below is the relevant bit of my code:

```
__fastcall TForm1::TForm1(TComponent* Owner)
    : TForm3D(Owner)
{
    mkView = new MKView(this);
    mkView->Align = TAlignLayout::Client;
    mkView->Enabled = true;
    mkView->Visible = true;
    mkView->Parent = this;
}

__fastcall MKView::MKView(TComponent *Owner)
    : TPanel(Owner)
{
    this->OnMouseDown = MKView_OnMouseDown;

    TLabel1 = new TLabel(this);
    TLabel1->Text = "Here I am!";
    TLabel1->Enabled = true;
    TLabel1->Visible = true;
    TLabel1->Parent = this;
    TLabel1->OnMouseDown = MKView_OnMouseDown;
}
```

Comment: There is no difference between creating a component dynamically at runtime versus placing it on the Form at design-time.  When loaded at runtime, design-time objects stored in the DFM are created dynamically anyway, similar to what you have shown (though you should be setting the `Parent` before setting the other properties).  So, something else is going on to keep your objects from appearing.  And BTW, don't set `this->OnMouseDown`, override the virtual `MouseDown()` method instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like TForm3D doesn't work well with standard FireMonkey components, as it is designed for rendering FireMonkey 3D components and uses OnRender() instead of OnPaint(). I was using TForm3D for its OpenGL context, but having switched to a standard TForm the components are now being drawn.